# Newton.Json.DeserializeObject vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm new trying to use Newton.Json.ConvertObject with VB.net
If someone could tell me how to use it and put my JSON into an array, this is my file:

```
{
"nombre":
    ["Alex","Carlos","Diego","Laura","Nancy"]
}
```

and I tried to use:

```
Public Class objMarcas
    Public Property marca() As String
End Class

Dim fileMarcas As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\instAplicativoCCR\marcas.json")
    Dim arrMarcas As objMarcas
    arrMarcas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of objMarcas)(fileMarcas)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match your JSON format,

```
Public Class objMarcas
 Public Property nombre() As List(Of String)
End Class
```

Then you do a foreach loop to get the string in the list. (You may want to check if arrMarcas is null and arrMarcas.nombre.Count is greater than 0 before calling the foreach loop)

```
For Each s As String In arrMarcas.nombre
    'Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

Comment: No need to check a count - if it is 0 then the loop exits.